# Как во float поправить обтекание?

Tags: javascript, css

Как можно настроить обтекание во float, чтобы не было такого заполнения по одному слову ? 
А было, допустим, только на 1-2 строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px
}
.parent p {
  text-align: justify
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>velu</div>
  <div>Blanditiis</div>
  <div>nulla</div>
  <div>am</div>

<p>Ai Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim ducimus atque maxime dolorum fugit beatae, veritatis quam? Blanditiis cupiditate minima nulla magnam ipsa totam dolorum vel, quaerat nobis, molestiae maiores.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну допустим вот так можно. Но ведь так вас не устроит, верно? Места нет, чтобы перенос первого слога Lor сработал с `hyphens: auto`.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px
}

.parent p {
  text-align: justify;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>velu</div>
  <div>Blanditiis</div>
  <div>nulla</div>
  <div>am</div>

  <p>Ai Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim ducimus atque maxime dolorum fugit beatae, veritatis quam? Blanditiis cupiditate minima nulla magnam ipsa totam dolorum vel, quaerat nobis, molestiae maiores.</p>
</div>
```

Еще можно простенький типограф написать на js, который меняет пробел после коротких слов на неразрывный пробел.

**UPD:** Пришла в голову еще одна идея:

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  letter-spacing: -.05em;
}

.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
}

.parent p {
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>velu</div>
  <div>Blanditiis</div>
  <div>nulla</div>
  <div>am</div>

  <p>Ai Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim ducimus atque maxime dolorum fugit beatae, veritatis quam? Blanditiis cupiditate minima nulla magnam ipsa totam dolorum vel, quaerat nobis, molestiae maiores.</p>
</div>
```

**UPD2:** Меня уже не остановить, еще мысль. )))

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-stretch: condensed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px
}

.parent p {
  text-align: justify;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<div class="parent">
  <div>Lorem</div>
  <div>consectetur</div>
  <div>velu</div>
  <div>Blanditiis</div>
  <div>nulla</div>
  <div>am</div>

  <p>Ai Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim ducimus atque maxime dolorum fugit beatae, veritatis quam? Blanditiis cupiditate minima nulla magnam ipsa totam dolorum vel, quaerat nobis, molestiae maiores.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Устраивают любые варианты. Интересно, как решают задачи профессионалы. Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! Мощно, конечно, подошли к вопросу =)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем конечно понятен вопрос. Тех же флоатов сколько может быть, насколько длинными могут быть слова, и по одному или не только, родительский блок каким может быть в размере, короче вопросов много. Может быть вариант следующий. Флоаты взять в отдельный блок, ну и по коду дальше, думаю, разберетесь. Смотрите:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent__float {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.parent {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 130px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.parent div {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.parent p {
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent__float">
  <div class="parent">
    <div>Lorem</div>
    <div>consectetur</div>
    <div>velu</div>
    <div>Blanditiis</div>
    <div>nulla</div>
    <div>am</div>
  </div>
  <p>Ai Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim ducimus atque maxime dolorum fugit beatae, veritatis quam? Blanditiis cupiditate minima nulla magnam ipsa totam dolorum vel, quaerat nobis, molestiae maiores.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. правило для флоатов
   если дети плывут - родители отвечают за это.
   например:

   .parent{
       clear:both;
       display:table;
   }
   .parent div{
   float:left;
   }